# QProcess output on large data

Tags: c++, qt5, stdout, qprocess

I need to zip a really large files (up to **13GB**) inside QT, while not overflowing the memory and getting the output of the zip correctly using **QProcess**. This is the code I got:

```
void zipFile(QString filename, QStringList files)
{
    QProcess process; 
    process.setStandardOutputFile(filename);
    process.setProgram("zip");
    process.setArguments(QStringList() << "-jr" << "-" << files);
    process.start(QProcess::ReadWrite | QProcess::Unbuffered);

    if (process.waitForStarted()) {
        process.waitForFinished(); /* Timeout here */

        if (process.exitStatus() != QProcess::NormalExit) {
            /* Deal with the error */
            return;
        }
    } else {
        /* Deal with the error */
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the **waitForFinished** function timeout and my process exit with problems, and I don't want to remove the timeout. There is a better way to do this using **QProcess**?

Comment: I would not wait for finished that will make your GUI unresponsive for the entire time that the background operation is running. Instead dynamically create your `QProcess` and have you application process the finished() signal.

Comment: Running `zip` like that seems to be a suicide in terms of safety TBH. You may want use QuaZip, which would let you reimplement this behavior with pretty much no effort.

Comment: @drescherjm The process responsible to call QProcess is already in a separated thread, so the GUI is no problem here.

Comment: `bool waitForFinished(int msecs = 30000)` the default arguments wait up to 30 seconds. If you need longer specify that..

Comment: @KamilKoczurek Maybe that is a good choice, but sadly, in the moment the decision to use a external library is not on me.